# SimpleDOM получение следующего тега

Tags: php, парсер

Есть текст:

```
<p>my text</p>
<a>link text</a>
<div>my text</div>
```

Я получил текст между p

```
$a = $html->find('p',0);
echo $a->plaintext;
```

Как получить текст из div? количество a, p и div множество. Никаких определений у div по классу и прочему нет, нужно именно получить следующий тег div.

Comment: следующий тег a будет

Comment: @Neatek Выложите исходник страницы на PASTEBIN.Без него гадать бессмысленно(если реально много такого добра).Посоветую только посмотреть,состоит ли требуемый <div> в каком-то уже определенном уже узле и его можно идентифицировать.Идентифицировали - достаем нужный div

Comment: @Naumov Автору это скорее не подходит `количество a, p и div множество`

Comment: @Maksym Вы наверное не правильно прочитали он выбирает `<p>` т.к. выхывает поиск по `find('p',0)`  и думает что это `a` я просто поправил его по идеи должно помочь `$html->find('a',0)->next()` хотя непонятно что он хочет

Comment: @Naumov Соглашусь.Не понятно)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте навигацию по `DOM`. Начинается навигация с `body`, или любого другого элемента.

У `DOM`-элементов есть свойства `firstElementChild` (первый дочерний элемент) и `lastElementChild` (последний дочерний элемент). После того как вы решили, какой тег будет у вас корневым, и получили его первый элемент, может перемещаться по его дочерним тегам вперед (`nextElementSibling`) и назад (`previousElementSibling`).

Вот вам пример, для наглядности. В нем много `div`'ов и все они на одно лицо (без `id` или `class`), но только в одном содержится нужное нам слово (win):

```js
var root=document.getElementById("root");
var winNode=root.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
alert(winNode.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div>
    <div>fail</div>
    <div>
      <div>fail</div>
      <div>win</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: по тегам ясно что вопрос не про javascript